# How to set up custom unhandled exception handler in Tornado?

Tags: python, web, tornado

I'm trying to implement custom unhandled request exception logging with overriding of the `tornado.web.Application._handle_request_exception` method:

```
def _handle_request_exception(self, e):
    logging.error('error')  # Just for test.
```

But I see the same log output like:

```
2012-09-01 03:35:09,947 [7399] root ERROR: Uncaught exception GET / (127.0.0.1)
HTTPRequest(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

instead of my custom message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first of all, the `_handle_request_exception` method is in `RequestHandler`, not `Application`.

Secondly, you can't override a bound method with a new definition in the main namespace:

```
def _handle_request_exception(self, e):
    logging.error('error')
```

You need to subclass the `RequestHandler` class:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def _handle_request_exception(self, e):
        logging.error('error')
```

all of your handlers should then inherit from `BaseHandler`.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was to override the method in `Application` class instead of `RequestHandler`.